# Getting output (some integer L) like(9L) insted of 9 in mysql query which is used in python

Tags: python, mysql

Can any one tell me that why i am getting incorrect output .

```
 query=("select Id from project where ActiveFlg='Y' ")
 cursor.execute(query)
 active_project=cursor.fetchall()
 print(active_project)
```

**output** :

> ((9L,), (10L,))
>
> ((5L,), (3L,))

**Expected output** :

> (9,10)
>
> (5,3)

Comment: It is not wrong actually. Your database field is integer type , thats why it shows `L` after number. And it returns tuple of tuple. You can avoid the tuple.

Comment: can you tell me how to avoid it @Shaonshaonty . I am new so i don't know much about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not wrong per se. The data type of your table is `long`, so `L` gets appended. The method `cursor.fetchall()` returns your output as a `tuple`.

However, to get things the way you want it, try:

```
In [0]: output = ((9L,),(10L,))

In [1]: x = tuple(sum(output, ()))

In [2]: x
Out[2]: (9L, 10L)

In [3]: y = [int(i) for i in x]

In [4]: y
Out[4]: [9, 10]

In [5]: tuple(y)
Out[5]: (9, 10)
```

**Succinctly**, use:

```
In [6]: tuple([(int(i[0])) for i in output])
Out[6]: (9, 10)
```

`cursor.fetchall()` returns a set of rows. So in your case, do:

```
for row in active_project:
    x = tuple([(int(i[0])) for i in row])
    print x
```

Answer (score 0):

It's acceptable.

> The method fetches all (or all remaining) rows of a query result set and returns a list of tuples. [[ref]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html)

You can convert it to `list` for example:

```
active_project = [((9L,), (10L,)), ((5L,), (3L,))]
for item in active_project:
    print [int(x[0]) for x in item]
```

**Output:**

```
# [9, 10]
# [5, 3]
```

Comment: it is giving error(TypeError: 'long' object has no attribute '__getitem__').

Comment: check this: `active_project=list(cursor.fetchall())`

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid it by using this command.

```
view_as_list = [i[0] for i in active_project] # here i[0] takes every tuple's first value
print(view_as_list)
```